# C++ Error in object construction. Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, matrix, unresolved-external

I have three files, a main.cpp file meant for testing my functions, a header file for the class, and the cpp file where my objects and members are declared.

I am trying to construct my object `Matrix` in the main file and receiving error: `Error: LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Matrix::Matrix(int,int)" (??0Matrix@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main  Matrix Project`.

I can only assume this mean there is something wrong with my constructor.  I am using it as follows and neither of them work:

```
    Matrix* matrix = new Matrix(2, 3);
    Matrix test = Matrix(2, 3);
```

The constructor is declared in the *.h file as follows:

```
Matrix(int numRows, int numCols);
```

And then declared in the *.cpp file as follows:

```
public:
    Matrix(int numRows, int numCols) {
        rows = numRows;
        cols = numCols;
        arr = new double*[numCols];
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numCols; ++x) {
                arr[i][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.  I'm sure I'm missing something silly.

Thank you in advance!

**[EDIT]**

For the sake of information, I figured I'd say that the variables `rows`, `cols`, and `arr` are all declared above the constructor as `private` members of the class.

Comment: you are not allocating the columns of the matrix!

Comment: Looks like your *.cpp is not compiled before the link phase.

Comment: @simpel01 I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the .cpp file you should put the *definition* of the method which has been *declared* in the header (.h) file. Therefore your .cpp file should look like:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int numRows, int numCols) { }
```

What you are doing is replicate the class definition in the .cpp file so that why you get the linking error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should have posted my entire code so one of you could tell me that I :

**A**. Will receive an error for redefining the class in my *.cpp file, and

**B**.  Needed to `include` my *.h file in the *.cpp file so it knows where to get the class declaration.  I'm sorry for wasting your time with this.